# What method do I use to change the interpreter string representation of a class instance

Tags: python, class, methods

I know

```
__str__
```

works for most uses of strings.

But what about when I simply write the instance and press enter in the interpreter?

Currently it returns something like `<__main__.class at 0xaea0080>`, what method do I use to overwrite that?

Comment: please don't put tags in your titles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `__repr__`. Note also that if `__str__` is not specified, it defaults to `__repr__`, but it's rare for this to be useful if you're using them right.

It's a common convention is that `__repr__`'s result should either look like a constructor call or be surrouned with `<>`, but it is *not* intended to be `eval`'ed in either case.

Lots of better examples here: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: note that a `repr` is intentionally different — it's meant to expose useful details to programmers, and usually takes the form `<ClassName ...>`